# Validar si una fecha es mayor a otra

Tags: java

Tengo una fecha actual y una fecha de inicio, necesito validar que la fecha de inicio sea mayor o igual a la fecha actual. La fecha de inicio esta en  `String` ya que recibe de un `input type="date"` y la otra fecha actual si en variable Date.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esta validación ?

```
Date fechaactual = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

String Dateinicio = request.getParameter("addtimeinicio");
tareas.setFechaasignada(date.format(fechaactual));
```

Comment: En que formato agregan la fecha en el input, pudrías poner un ejemplo?

Answer (score 5):

Puedes utilizar los métodos que contiene `Date`, ya sea `after` o `before`, que se encarga de comparar las fechas ambos devuelven un valor de tipo `boolean`:

`after` = Comprueba si esta fecha es posterior a la fecha especificada.

`before` = 
Comprueba si esta fecha es anterior a la fecha especificada.

Usando lo anterior he realizado de nuevo el código:

```java
Date fechaactual = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
String fechaInicio = "2008-01-12"; //fecha de ejemplo
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date fechaInicioDate = date.parse(fechaInicio);  //String a date

 //comprueba si es que inicio esta después que fecha actual       
if(fechaInicioDate.after(fechaactual)){
    System.out.println("Fecha inicio mayor");
}else{
    System.out.println("Fecha actual mayor");
}
```

He creado un valor de tipo `String` simulando la fecha inicial, después la he transformado a un valor de tipo `Date`, para poder realizar la comparación bajo el formato previamente dado, dentro del `if` compruebo con `after`  si la fecha de inicio está después que la fecha actual , entonces el `mensaje` será *fecha inicio mayor* sino *fecha actual mayor*.

**Resultado:**

Dejo el resultado con dos fechas comparadas a las de hoy, `2008` que da *fecha actual mayor* y con `2022` que da *fecha inicio mayor*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Primero deberías crear tu variable Date "fechainicio", despues cargarla con el valor correspondiente y comparar ambas, sería algo así:

```
Date fechainicio = date.Parse(Dateinicio);

if (fechainicio.compareTo(fechaactual) >= 0) {  
            System.out.println("La fecha Inicio ocurre el mismo día o después de la fecha Actual"); 
        }         

// El método compareTo devuelve el valor mayor que 0 si fechainicio está después del argumento fechaactual
// Devuelve cero si son iguales
```

Saludos!